# Change Text and Icon using jQuery

Tags: jquery

When you click on "Hide Information", I would like to change the text from "Hide Information" to "Show Information" and also change the icon: https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-and-data/500/view-content-window-16.png.

When the text is clicked again, it should change from "Show Information" to "Hide Information".

Please remember that when you show information the text "teststests" shall display. If you want to hide "teststests" you click on the "Hide Information".

I don't know how to do it.

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#test").click(function(){
        $("#test2").toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test2" style="display:none">
teststests
</div>

<div id="test">
<img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/octicons/1024/eye-16.png" /> Show Information
</div>
```

Comment: Check my post, I've included the CSS that would prevent the divs from overlapping when they fade in and out. This would also work for '.fadeToggle()' on Amit's answer. I was unable to add the CSS to my fiddle as I've just posted this comment and edit on my phone, and for some reason it's not letting me target the CSS field on there aha. You can just copy and paste it in and it'll work fine. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6o04a6g6/2/)**

code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#test,div#test2").click(function(){        
        $("div#test,div#test2").toggle();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="test">
<img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/octicons/1024/eye-16.png" /> Show Information
</div>

<div id="test2" style="display:none">
    <div>teststests</div>
<img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-and-data/500/view-content-window-16.png"/>
    hide information
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the text "teststests"?

Comment: @HelloWorld You want that always to be displayed ? If yes let me update the answer

Comment: This is a better answer than mine. Vote.

Answer (score 0):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g4z4gw3q/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="show" style="opacity: 1;">Click this to show (insert wanted icon)</div>

<div id="hide" style="opacity: 0;">Click this to hide (insert another icon)</div>

<p id="text" style="opacity: 0;">testest</p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#show').click(function(){
$('#show').fadeOut(500, 0);
$('#text').fadeTo(500, 1);
$('#hide').fadeTo(500, 1);
});
$('#hide').click(function(){
$('#show').fadeTo(500, 1);
$('#text').fadeOut(500, 0);
$('#hide').fadeTo(500, 0);
});
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#hide, #show{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}
```

Comment: What text? "Show information" and "Hide Information"?

Comment: Check the new fiddle.

Comment: What HelloWorld wants is when you click "show info", document will show "teststests", if you click "hide info", "teststests" will be hided.

Comment: Yeah I've just fixed it. It wasn't in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you are using an font-awesome for your icon and jquery for your javascript

your markup

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle show"><i class="fa fa-hide"></i> Show Information</a>
</div>
```

Your jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('show') ) {
            //replace the text
            $(this).text('Hide information');
            //replace the icon
            $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-hide').addClass('fa-show');
            $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide);
        } else {
            //replace the text
            $(this).text('Show information');
            //replace the icon
            $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-show').addClass('fa-hide');
            $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass('show);                
        }
    });
});
```

That should do
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you want:

js part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#test").click(function(){

     if ($('#test2').css('display') == 'none') {
      $("#test2").show();
        $("#changeme").html("Hide Information");
         $("#changeimg").attr("src","https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/seo-and-data/500/view-content-window-16.png");
}     
        else{
            $("#test2").hide();
        $("#changeme").html("Show Information");
            $("#changeimg").attr("src","https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/octicons/1024/eye-16.png");

        }   
 });
});
```

You just need to change a little in the html like adding an ID:

```
<div id="test2" style="display:none">
teststests
</div>



<div id="test">
<img id="changeimg" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/octicons/1024/eye-16.png" /> 
<span id="changeme">Show Information</span>
</div>
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/2pys32qj/